# How can I save a Facebook album photo to my server if the user has authenticated and granted user_photos permission?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, upload, photo

My Facebook app shows the user a collection of photos from one of their Facebook photo albums.  I am trying to allow the user to select a photo for uploading to my application, to be stored on my server.  I have built the app in Ruby on Rails, and hosting it on Heroku.  Planning to use an S3 bucket for storing the images.  Is there anything in Ruby that is well suited for this task, like the CarrierWave Gem, or perhaps do it in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

If using carrierwave you can use the remote_location option and just pass in the URL Facebook provides to the image. https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave#uploading-files-from-a-remote-location

Carrier Wave also supports fog so your integration with amazon s3 will be easier.